# Rail traffic is backed up trying to leave my city. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: cities-skylines

I've got a long line of trains trying to leave my city on one of the pre-made connections to the foggy lands. It's become a traffic problem within the city and I'm looking for a way to clear it up.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the best way to prevent this happening is to:

- Keep cargo and passenger train lines separate
- Don't connect your passenger train lines to the external world connections

The first really just enables the second (because you *do* want your cargo lines connected to the world, so they'll have to be separate). The second prevents trains coming in from outside brining in tourists - of which you seem to get *way too many* that go on to clog everything up.

If you want to still get visitors coming in by train from the outside world, then connect the world train line to a station next to a transport hub of some kind, let the tourists transfer onto you local line, metro, buses, etc.

In terms of rail network construction, avoid compact rail track t-junctions; three trains can deadlock in this situation (which unsurprisingly causes all manner of problems). Ideally the links should be at least a train length apart.

Comment: But external train connections bring in tourists.  I think the better approach is to keep your commuter train network mostly separate, while also having interconnects to the outside world.

Comment: I do kinda say that when I talk about brining a link for the external line into a station next to a transport hub somewhere.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution to me. Perhaps I can devote one whole incoming train line to tourism. There are three on my map